# Property 'handleSubmit' does not exist on type 'Login'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs

Am I supposed to import or install something?
I get the error 'Property 'handleSubmit' does not exist on type 'Login'.ts(2339)'

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="form-wrapper">
          <h1>Create Account</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Your Login class has no `handleSubmit` method.  Write one.  Simple as that.

Comment: Do some research before asking questions. It's just a google away.
Create handleSubmit function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a method named `handleSubmit` in your class.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Login extends Component {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log('this works');
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="form-wrapper">
          <h1>Create Account</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a handleSubmit function that will be executed when submit happens, for example:

```
class Login extends Component {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("Submit clicked!");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
  ...
```